# express.static ha dejado de servir un archivo

Tags: express

Estaba haciendo pruebas, y, en una de ellas, he marcado la casilla `disable cache` en la pestaña de herramientas de red del navegador. Desde ese momento, `express.static` **ha dejado de servirme 1 archivo**. Siempre el mismo.
Por supuesto, el archivo sigue estando en el mismo sitio:

> static/
>     webix.js
>     index.html
>     navigo.min.js
>     drivers/
>         webixui.js
>         misc.js
>         navigorouter.js

El código de mi servidor es:

```
// Las rutas que uso:

app.post( '/config.json', function( req, res ) {
    res.json( require( './app/config/main.js' ) );
    res.end( );
} );

app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
    console.log( req.url );
    next( );
}, express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'static' ) ) );
```

Simple como el mecanismo de un chupete. La parte del `console.log( )` la he puesto para comprobar las solicitudes que estoy recibiendo:

> /webix.js
> /navigo.min.js
> /drivers/webixui.js
> /drivers/misc.js
> /drivers/navigorouter.js
> /skins/mini.min.css

Se observa que **si** recibo la solicitud. Sin embargo, el navegador no obtiene respuesta a la misma.

El mecanismo de carga es *personalizado*: obtengo mediante `POST` un `JSON`, y uno de sus campos contiene los archivos `.js` a cargar. El código para esto es:

```
if( 'js' in config ){
    config.js.forEach( function( item ) {
        ++loadsCount;
        const ref = document.createElement( 'script' );
        ref.onload = resourceLoaded;
        document.head.appendChild( ref );
        ref.src = item;
        console.log( `Begin src ${item}` );
    } );
}
```

Mediante el `console.log( )` veo que, ciertamente, la solicitud se está realizando:

> Begin src webix.js (index):94
> Begin src navigo.min.js (index):94
> Begin src drivers/webixui.js (index):94
> Begin src drivers/misc.js (index):94
> Begin src drivers/navigorouter.js (index):94
> Begin href skins/mini.min.css (index):112

Y en la pestaña `Herramientas de Red` puedo confirmarlo: el navegador solicita todo lo que tiene que solicitar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Examinando las cabeceras enviadas por el navegador, no observo nada *raro*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con todo eso, en principio descarto cualquier problema en la parte del navegador. He comprobado (al principio de la pregunta) que el `node.js` está recibiendo correctamente las solicitudes. Y mi servidor no responde con un `404` ni ningún tipo de error; simplemente, no envía respuesta para **ese** archivo en concreto.

He borrado la caché del navegador, pero no hay forma. Ese archivo no se ha vuelto a servir. Y al usar otro navegador, ocurre algo similar: el archivo se ha servido **1 sola vez**, la primera. Y a partir de ahí, se repite el comportamiento observado: el archivo no se sirve.

¿ Como puedo solucionar este archivo *fantasma* ?

Comment: +1 por una pregunta muy bien formulada. Aunque quizás estaría bien que incluyeras la línea de index.html que causa la solicitud de webix.js. Supongo que será un `<script src="...">`, pero por si acaso se ve algo raro en ella

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si envías otro archivo en vez del archivo "fantasma" te lo envia o no?

Comment: @Franco Me los envía todos ... menos ese. Todas las demás solicitudes a `node` se responden correctamente (como se puede ver en la imagen de la pestaña de red). Todas las solicitudes son *dinámicas* y se han generado igual, a partir del `JSON` de configuración.

Comment: Que raro, lo único que se me ocurre es que halla algo mal en tu archivo, yo intentaría cambiarle el nombre y enviarlo con el nombre cambiado

Comment: Raro como un perro verde :-( Y encima no es mio, es el `.js` de [Webix](https://docs.webix.com/), que es la librería principal que estoy usando. Y sin embargo, el `mini.min.css` que también pertenece a `Webix` me lo sirve correctamente.

Comment: en que sistema operativo estas trabajando? Puede que el servidor no tenga los permisos de lectura del archivo, haz un `ls -alh` a la carpeta de estaticos para verificar los permisos

Comment: @JuniorUsca `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`. El archivo problemático se descargó mediante `npm install`, y luego **lo copié yo a mano** a su ubicación definitiva. Todos los archivos tienen `-rw-rw-r--` (lectura para todos los usuarios), y los directorios `drwxrwxr-x` (lectura y *ejecución* para todos).

Comment: prueba usando el webix.min.js, ya que el otro pesa 1.4M es muy grande, sino prueba usando el cdn https://webix.com/quick_start/ .
Al parecer el error es problema de node https://stackoverflow.com/a/63736472/4440167

Comment: @JuniorUsca Pues mucho me temo que va a ser lo que dices, un problema en `node`/`express`. Pues vaya *faena* :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea cargar dinámicamente una serie de archivos estáticos mediante peticiones a un servidor [Express](https://expressjs.com/) / [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/es/), sin embargo hay problemas durante la carga de los archivos estáticos, en particular en la carga de uno de los mismos.

Al analizar el código que maneja el envío de la configuración dinámica (archivo `.json`) se observa lo siguiente:

```js
app.post( '/config.json', function( req, res ) {
    res.json( require( './app/config/main.js' ) );
    res.end( );
} );
```

Como se observa tienes 2 llamadas a métodos diferentes: [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) y [`res.end()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) en la misma solicitud `post`. Esto causa algo llamado como *condición de carrera* (*race condition*), ya que el método `res.json()` debe convertir a formato JSON el objeto recibido como argumento, y a la vez, la solicitud es finalizada con `res.end()`, dando por terminado el proceso *solicitud/respuesta*, dejando el proceso del método `res.json()` sin finalizar, por lo tanto no se estaría enviando correctamente el archivo `json` al cliente.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, elimina la llamada a `res.end()` de tu middleware, dejando el código tan solo con:

```js
app.post( '/config.json', function( req, res ) {
    res.json( require( './app/config/main.js' ) );
    // res.end( ); <- esto debes eliminarlo
} );
```

De esta forma el proceso de *solicitud / respuesta* finalizará correctamente, siendo enviado el archivo `json` al cliente para que el mismo pueda realizar la carga dinámica de los recursos de la carpeta `static` de Express.

De acuerdo a la documentación: (traducción propia)

> **res.end([data] [, encoding])**
>
> Finaliza el proceso de respuesta. Este método realmente viene de Node, específicamente del método `response.end()` del objeto `http.ServerResponse`.
>
> Se usa para finalizar rápidamente la respuesta sin enviar datos. Si se necesita responder con algún tipo de dato, se debe usar otro método, tal como `res.send()` y `res.json()`.

Dicho esto, no hace falta llamar explícitamente el método `res.end()` cuando se usa `res.json()` ya que este último finaliza el proceso de respuesta internamente.